# нужно ли bootstrap-4 scss пропускать через autoprefixer

Tags: gulp, sass, bootstrap4, autoprefixer

```
gulp.task( 'style:dev' ,( ) => {

    return gulp.src( conf.styleMain )

        .pipe( sass() )
        .pipe( autoprefixer( conf.pref ) )
        .pipe( gcmq() )
        .pipe( cssbeautify() )
        .pipe( plumber() )
        .pipe( addsrc.prepend( conf.styleLibs ) ).pipe( sass() )
        .pipe( concat('app.css') )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( conf.build.style ) )
        .pipe( cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie8'}) )
        .pipe( removeComments() )
        .pipe( rename( conf.rename ) )
        .pipe( plumber() )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( conf.build.style ) )
        .pipe( web.stream() )

//  End css dev task
} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по тому, что написано в доках Bootstrap про Autoprefixer ([тут](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/build-tools/#autoprefixer)), нужно. Они не вносят в код вендор-префиксы, а используют для этого Autoprefixer на этапе сборки.